# How to pass object to question mark method

Tags: java, spring

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
  Service<?> s = determine(args[0]);

  //getting error here: cannot pass Object to ?
  s.process(new Object());
}

static Service<?> determine(String name){
   //return a service
}

interface Service<I> {
  void process(I in);
}
```

I'm not able to pass my Object to service method. Why and how to resolve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Service<?>` instance's `process` method accepts an instance of a specific *but unknown* class.

You can't directly create a `Service<?>`: you have to create an instance of with a concrete value of the type variable. All of the following are subtypes of `Service<?>`: `Service<Object>`, `Service<Integer>`, `Service<Map<String, List<Object>>>` etc. The `process` method of these example types expect an `Object`, `Integer` and `Map<String, List<Object>>` respectively.

But the compiler doesn't know which of these it is, so it doesn't allow you to invoke the `process` method with a non-null value, because it might be the wrong kind of non-null value.

You can only invoke this with a literal `null`, which is the only thing that can be cast to any type.

```
s.process(null);
```

If you want to be able to pass `Object` into the `process` method, you have to make `determine` return a `Service<Object>`; or remove the type variable from the `Service` interface, and make `process` just accept `Object`.

Comment: I decide to use raw type. Thanks for your replying

Comment: No. [Don't use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). If you need to be able to pass "anything" into the Service, remove the generic and make `process` accept a plain `Object`.

Comment: The difference is that using Object places the burden onto the implementor of `Service` to handle the fact it might be given something of the wrong type; using raw types makes it look to the caller like you can pass anything, and to the implementor of the interface like they will get a specific type. Things may fail immediately, or maybe proceed OK until much later, when it turns out that you have introduced heap pollution and you get a random, untraceable failure elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I mean raw type of `determine(String name)`. It will return raw Service. Is it ok?

Comment: No. Don't use raw types at all. They exist purely for backwards compatibility with code written pre-Java 5 (which was released nearly 20 years ago). Do not use them in new code.

Comment: I cannot make `process` accept Object. It must be <I>. And the `determine` will return Service<I> which <I> will be dynamic. So the method signature must be <?> or raw type. Am i correct?

Comment: `I` may be dynamic; but unless you know something about the concrete type, you cannot safely pass in a non-null value. The code's design is fundamentally broken from a type safety perspective.

Comment: For the code you've shown above, a better approach is to use a `switch (name)` inside the `main` method: then you can choose an appropriate `Service<String>`, `Service<Integer>` etc and process it type-correctly.